# Package is found by dpkg but cannot be removed

Tags: package-management, dpkg, software-center, uninstall

I have installed a .deb file with the Software Center (Or just "Software" how its called now). I want to uninstall it now. The Software Center doesn't list it under the installed programs.

`dpkg -l | grep megasync`

does show that it is installed:

```
ii  megasync 4.0.2+1.1 amd64 Easy automated syncing between your computers and your MEGA cloud drive
```

However

```
sudo dpkg -p megasync # alternatively -r
```

as it has been suggested by all other threads I've found about this, yields "dpkg-query: package 'megasync' is not available". What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: How about `apt remove`?

Comment: It... worked? Why though, I didn't install it with apt! Thanks for the help

Comment: All installed packages go into the Apt database, so can (indeed, should) be removed with `apt remove` (or `apt-get remove`). I'm not sure why `dpkg -r` didn't work, though (hence not an answer).